# IRB - unfinished expression at operator's symbol?

Tags: ruby, irb

Can anybody explain why some of operator symbols cann't be written directly as symbols in irb, whereas when passed to ruby interpreter it runs without any issue ?
It looks like irb parses an expression as unfinished and prompts with an asterisk as awaiting continue of input:

```
irb> test_symbol = :+
irb*  ^C
irb> test_symbol = :-
irb*  ^C
irb> test_symbol = :*
=> :*
irb> test_symbol = :<
=> :<
```

Other symbols that fail at parsing are `:%`, `:&`, `:^`, `:/`, `:|`, `:~` . I *can* pass those symbols as strings, ie. `test_symbol = :'+'` however this is just a workaround to a possible bug. Or a feature ?

Can somebody shed some light to this behaviour ?

Comment: `test_symbol = :+` works fine for me using ruby 2.0.0-p247 and irb 0.9.6. What version of `irb` are you using?

Comment: @Zajn 1.9.3-p484 . I can confirm it does work in 2.0.0-p353. Any link to ane existing bugreport ?

Answer (score 1):

I installed `1.9.3dev` on my machine and can confirm that `irb` does appear to be "awaiting input" after using a symbol like that.

However, this doesn't actually affect how the eval loop functions. As an example, I tried this:

```
irb(main):001:0> test_symbol = :+
irb(main):002:0* 2.send test_symbol, 1
=> 3
```

So while it seems that IRB is waiting for you to finish an expression, it does seemt to parse the expression correctly. I can't find any bug reports around this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the report ! I also cann't find a bug report at ruby-lang.org however it seems to get fixed for 2.0.0 or it may be a side effect of other changes.